# How to set Connection Pool log to track Abandoned Connection/Clients?

Tags: java, connection-pooling, mysql-connector

I use  MySQL 5.7.33 J-connector 8.0.22 JDK 11 on a stand alone executable jar application not running on TomCat.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
 <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
  <version>2.11.1</version>
```

I have tried this

```
 ds = new BasicDataSource();
 ds.setInitialSize(1);
 ds.setMinIdle(1);
 ds.setMaxIdle(2);
 ds.setMaxTotal(4);
 ds.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(500);
 ds.setMaxConnLifetimeMillis(2400);
 ds.setMaxWaitMillis(6000);
 ds.setSoftMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(500);
 ds.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(500);

File file = new File("c:\\logs\\connectionLog.log");
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(file);
ds.setLogExpiredConnections(true);
ds.setAbandonedUsageTracking(true);
ds.setLogWriter(printWriter);
ds.setLogExpiredConnections(true);
ds.setAbandonedLogWriter(printWriter);
ds.setLogAbandoned(true);
```

Log file.exists() returns true but it's blank. The application runs correctly. It connects to MySQL and can select/update/insert alright. How do I set up the log correctly to see Abandoned Connections/Clients so they can be traced back to root causes? Please advice.